# Error calling object of function references

Tags: typescript, ts-node

I have something like this:

```js
const fn1 = (param1: string, param2: string, param3: string): Promise<void> => {return new Promise()}

const fn2 = (param1: string, param2: string): void => {return}

const options = {
  option1: fn1,
  option2: fn2,
  option3: fn1,
  option4: fn2,
}

const myOption = 'option1';
const myParam1 = 'a';
const myParam2 = 'b';
const myParam3 = 'c';

options[myOption](myParam1, myParam2, myParam3); // ERROR in this line
```

I did it with Javascript at first but then I had to transform it into TS. The linter doesn't find any problem, but when I try to run it with ts-node it shows the following error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type...[the type object here]
```

How can I type the object to be able to call the functions inside avoiding to use a switch/case or infinite else/if?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the best answer, but it worked:

```js
const options: Record<string, typeof fn1 | typeof fn2> = {
  option1: fn1,
  option2: fn2,
  option3: fn1,
  option4: fn2,
}
```

Typescript doesn't seem to recognize option1, option2... as strings but as an enum.

Comment: The problem here is that you can for example do `options['option5'](myParam1, myParam2, myParam3)`, which causes an error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting this error running the code with ts-node, but what you could try is to set type of myOption to:

```js
const myOption: keyof typeof options = 'option1';
```

Comment: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"option1" | "option2" | "option3"'.ts(2322)
myOption comes from a string array.

Answer (score 0):

If `myOption` is coming from a string array you can define a typeguard to make sure it is of type `keyof typeof options`, which is the correct indexing type for your `options` object.

```
   function isKeyOfOptions(value: string): value is keyof typeof options {
      return options[value] !== undefined;
    }

    if(isKeyOfOptions(str))
       options[str](myParam1, myParam2, myParam3) 
       // str type in this block is "option1" | "option2" | "option3" | "option4";
```